# Python : Iterate through list and sublists and match first elements and do some more manipulations

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python, so want to know if there is built in function or other way to do below in python 2.7:

Iterate through list and sublists and if value of first element matches with value of first sublist element, delete first sublist element and put other elements in sublist in outside list. Do this for all sublists. See below examples for better understanding of my requirement.

Examples:

```
Input  : ['or', ['or', 'R', '-B'], 'W']
Output : ['or', 'R', '-B', 'W']
```

Here, 'or' , 'or' matched in main list and sublist, so remove 'or' in sublist and put other elements in sublist 'R' and '-B' in main list

```
Input : ['and', ['and', ['or', '-P', 'R'], ['or', 'Q', 'R']], ['or', '-P', '-R']]
Output : ['and', ['or', '-P', 'R'], ['or', 'Q', 'R'], ['or', '-P', '-R']]
```

Here, 'and' , 'and' matched in main list and sublist

```
Input : ['and', ['and', ['or', 'A', 'C'], ['or', 'A', 'D']], ['and', ['or', 'B', 'C'], ['or', 'B', 'D']]]
Output : ['and', ['or', 'A', 'C'], ['or', 'A', 'D'], ['or', 'B', 'C'], ['or', 'B', 'D']]
```

Here, 'and' , 'and' matched in main list and sublist1, so remove 'and' in sublist1 and put other elements in sublist1 in main list. Also 'and' , 'and' matched in main list and sublist2, so remove 'and' in sublist2 and put other elements in sublist2 in main list.

Hope I explained my questions clearly with examples

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do this recursively, or one-deep, as in all the examples? What have you tried so far? There certainly isn't a builtin method to do this, but it would be relatively simple to code with list manipulation.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do this recursively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two work: one recursively, one not. However, they *only* work for lists, which is annoying. If I switch to checking for iterables, then they'll eat up the strings. I'll figure out a good fix for this in a moment.

```
def condense(l):
    outp = [l[0]] 
    for x in l[1:]:
        if isinstance(x,list) and x[0]==l[0]:
            outp += x[1:]
        else:
            outp.append(x)
    return outp
def condense_r(l):
    outp = [l[0]] 
    for x in l[1:]:
        if isinstance(x,list):
            z = condense_r(x)
            if z[0]==l[0]:
                outp += z[1:]
            else:
                outp.append(z)
        else:
            outp.append(x)
    return outp
```

Essentially, these just go through and check for what you were saying.

---

Update:

If you'd rather be able to operate on generic sequences, then this will work: it checks if it is a Sequence, and then makes sure it isn't a string:

```
import collections
def condense(l):
    outp = [l[0]] 
    for x in l[1:]:
        if isinstance(x,collections.Sequence) \
            and not isinstance(x,basestring) and x[0]==l[0]:
            outp += x[1:]
        else:
            outp.append(x)
    return outp
def condense_r(l):
    outp = [l[0]] 
    for x in l[1:]:
        if isinstance(x,collections.Sequence) and not isinstance(x,basestring):
            z = condense_r(x)
            if z[0]==l[0]:
                outp += z[1:]
            else:
                outp.append(z)
        else:
            outp.append(x)
    return outp
```